# Don't continue activity until alert dialog has been handled

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, synchronous

I am only showing an alert dialog once when the App is installed. In the alert dialog, the user has to select a country that is stored in a variable, before the app loads the data according to the selected country. I want it to wait until the alert dialog has been handled before it continue... Below is my code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    isFirstTime();
    initialize();
}

private void isFirstTime() {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean ranBefore = preferences.getBoolean("RanBefore", false);
    if (ranBefore == false) {
        String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries);
        final String[] countriesCode = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries_code);
        AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        mBuilder.setTitle("Choose country");
        mBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(countries, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                String selectedCountry = countriesCode[i];
                int selectedCountryIndex = i;
                SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("country", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                editor.putString("selectedCountry", selectedCountry);
                editor.putInt("selectedCountryIndex", selectedCountryIndex);
                editor.apply();
                dialogInterface.dismiss();

            }
        });
        mBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog mDialog = mBuilder.create();
        mDialog.show();

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("RanBefore", true);
        editor.apply();

    }

}


private void initialize(){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    NavigationDrawer navigationDrawer_fragment =
            (NavigationDrawer) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mainfragmentdrawer);
    navigationDrawer_fragment.setup((DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);


    final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Latest"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Categories"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I think there is some double-negation in your want. Do you mean that execution should wait until the user has responded to the Alert?

Comment: @JanAndersen Yes

Answer (score 0):

You could Change the

```
private void isFirstTime() {
```

Into

```
private bool isFirstTime() {
```

And add a return value based on the user's response to the dialog, which is then returned from the function at the end of it.

And nest initialize inside:

```
if (isFirstTime()) {
   initialize();
}
```

No awaits? Erm, which one of the dialogs is it?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final String COUNTRYSETTINGS = "countrySettings";
private static final String SHOWCNTRYDIALOG = "countryDialog";
Boolean showCountryDialog = false;
//keep a boolean which you set from the sharedpref 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(COUNTRYSETTINGS, 0);

   if(!pref.contains(SHOWCNTRYDIALOG)){
       pref.edit().putBoolean(SHOWCNTRYDIALOG, false).apply();
       showCountryDialog = true;
   }else{
       showCountryDialog = pref.getBoolean(SHOWCNTRYDIALOG, true);
   }
   if(showCountryDialog){
       createCountryDialog();
   }
}   
public void createCountryDialog(){
  //Handle your setting country related stuff
  if(postive_option)
     checkCountryAndLoadDataAcc();
}
```

Create a variable in shared pref with help of which you will show the dialog only for the first time of app install (showCountryDialog) and with help of which you call your dialog function in which you can check the location and call your load function further from there.